# How to invoke a method inside a external jar using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, jar, classloader

I want to invoke a method which inside a external .jar by using reflection.

This is a sample code which inside the jar.

```
public class HelloFunction implements Runnable, RequestHandler<Request> {

    @Override
    public void handle(final Request request) {
        System.out.println("handle : " + request);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("run......");
    }
}
```

Then i loaded this jar in a separate java program and tried to invoke HelloFunction.handle() method. This is the sample code for that part.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }

    public static void test(){

        try{

            final Class<?> functionClass = getClassFromFunctionJar("com.hello.HelloFunction");

            final Object functionClassObject = functionClass.newInstance();

            if(functionClassObject instanceof RequestHandler){

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final RequestHandler<Object> handler = RequestHandler.class.cast(functionClassObject);

                final Object inputObject = getRequestClass(functionClass).newInstance();

                handler.handle(inputObject);


            }

        }catch(final Exception e){

            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }

    public static Class<?> getRequestClass(final Class<?> cls) throws FunctionInvokerException{

        try{
            final Type[] types = cls.getGenericInterfaces();

            for(Type type : types){

                //check RequestHandler
                if(type.getTypeName().contains(RequestHandler.class.getName())){

                    final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;

                    // [0]=> Request Type
                    final String inputClassName = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0].getTypeName();
                    return getClassFromFunctionJar(inputClassName);

                }

            }

            throw new Exception("UNABLE_TO_FIND_REQUEST_TYPE");

        }catch(final Exception e){
            throw new FunctionInvokerException(e);
        }

    }

    private static Class<?> getClassFromFunctionJar(final String className) throws ClassNotFoundException, MalformedURLException{
        final ClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{new URL("file:" + "/jar-location/hello.jar")}, App.class.getClassLoader());
        return Class.forName(className, true, classLoader);
    }

}
```

You can see here i used getClassFromFunctionJar() method to load Class from a jar. And getRequestClass() method is used to find class type of the HelloFunction.handle() method's input parameter. 
Everything is fine until invoking handle() method.

Finally i got an error which says "com.hello.Request cannot be cast to com.hello.Request". Could you please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: why do you need reflection?

Comment: `com.hello.Request cannot be cast to com.hello.Request` ALWAYS means you have loaded the class twice, through two different classloaders.  You already have the class loaded statically due to the hardcoded reference, and you loaded a second copy when you loaded the implementation.  This is not posted as an answer because, while I can tell you WHY you got the error, there is not enough information to tell you how to fix it (and my class loader expertise is somewhat out of date).

Comment: Yes. Issue was i loaded classloader twise, now fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same class definition loaded by different class loaders is seen as two distinct classes by the JVM.

your code "URLClassLoader.newInstance" while get different class loaders

the first(handler#parameter) is: URLClassLoader#1 & com.hello.Request

the second(inputObject) is: URLClassLoader#2 & com.hello.Request

"com.hello.Request cannot be cast to com.hello.Request".

The actual error is

"URLClassLoader#2 com.hello.Request cannot be cast to  URLClassLoader#1 com.hello.Request"

and suggest this:

```
private static final ClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{new URL("file:" + "/jar-location/hello.jar")}, App.class.getClassLoader());

private static Class<?> getClassFromFunctionJar(final String className) throws ClassNotFoundException, MalformedURLException{
    return Class.forName(className, true, classLoader);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer. Now fixed it.